# Write to file code works on development, breaks when deployed to the store

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to write a line of text to a text file. On the emulator or running from VS on the device, it works perfectly but when downloaded from the store, this code emits the error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 
'C:\Data\Programs\{XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXX-XXXXX}\Install\Data\results.csv' is denied.
```

Here is my code:

```
var path = "Data/results.csv";
var uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).ToString();

using (var rd = new StreamWriter(uri, true))
{                
    var line = String.Format("{0};{1}", field1, field2);
    rd.WriteLine(line);                
    rd.Close();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can the code work on development?

Comment: I think you might need to use special methods to write to folders (to prevent apps from getting access to the whole filesystem). Try looking here, if it helps I'll write it up as an answer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @AndrewPiliser, what baffles me is that the code above works without a warning on the emulator or even on a device, when deployed from VS. This is madness! How can a developer used to .net program on this thing if some important techniques are useless? (sorry for the rant)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

It gets the storage that your app can use on users phone. You can then create directories (or files) for example:

```
iso.CreateDirectory("Data");
```

Why it works in emulator or on your device? I'd guess because MS does not care about access rights here.